# Existence of the norm over linear operators in infinite dimensional space

Tags: general-topology, analysis, vector-spaces

I was wondering how one can prove that for $E$ and $F$ infinite dimensional normed vectorial spaces, $T$ a linear operator going from $E$ to $F$, $\frac{\|T(u)\|_F}{\|u\|_E}$ has an upper bound for $u\in E$.

Comment: This will depend on the operator T since whenever E is infinite dimensional there exists a choice of T such that no upper bound exists

Comment: @RhysSteele This is interesting, could you provide an example?

Comment: For any infinite dimensional $E$ (assuming the axiom of choice) I can take a countable set of linearly independent norm 1 vectors $x_1, x_2, \dots$ and extend them to a (hamel) basis. Then you can obtain an unbounded linear functional by defining $f(x_n) = n$, setting $f$ to zero on the remainder of the basis and then extending linearly. If F is of dimension greater than 1 then just pick a non-zero $y \in F$ and consider $Tx = f(x)y$.

Comment: Consider $E=F=\Bbb{R}[X]$ equipped with the norm $\big\Vert\sum_{k=0}^n a_kX^k\big\Vert=\sum_{k=0}^n |a_k|$.
Define $T(f)=f'$.
Then for $f(X)=X^n$ we have $\frac{\Vert T(f)\Vert}{\Vert f\Vert}=n$.

Comment: @RhysSteele Sthank you

Comment: @jpboucheron Thank you